# Spring Transactions insert,select in one method

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ibatis

please could me somebody explain how working transaction in method, generally what is going. mapper is iBatis.

```
@Transactional
    public void insert(SameDto same) {

      sameDao.insert(same);
      webserice.call(same);
}
```

SameDao.class ->

```
@Transactional
public void insert(SameDto same) {
    mapper.updateToInvalidate(same);

    SameDto other = new SameDto(...); 
    BigDecimal primaryKey=  mapper.insert(other);
    SameDto equalsSameDto = mapper.getByPrimaryKey(primaryKey);


    continue ....

}
```

I don't understand because Object "equalsSameDto" is null. I could thinks that transaction is not committed yet. But it some legal way how to use it.

Thx for advise.

Comment: Spring Transaction with iBatis

Comment: Should be fine as it's described